# Flutter - A RenderFlex overflowed by 190 pixels on the bottom in showModalBottomSheet

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

My showModalBottomSheet showing bottom overflow error :
My Code of bottomSheet:

```
 loginSheet(BuildContext context) {
    return showModalBottomSheet(
        isScrollControlled: true,
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
            ),
            child: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.30,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 150.0),
                    child: Divider(
                      thickness: 4.0,
                      color: constantColors.whiteColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: userEmailController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Enter Email...',
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: constantColors.whiteColor,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 16.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: constantColors.whiteColor,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: userPasswordController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Enter Password...',
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: constantColors.whiteColor,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 16.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: constantColors.whiteColor,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  FloatingActionButton(
                    backgroundColor: constantColors.blueColor,
                    child: Icon(
                      FontAwesomeIcons.check,
                      color: constantColors.whiteColor,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (userEmailController.text.isNotEmpty) {
                        Provider.of<Authentication>(context, listen: false)
                            .logIntoAccount(userEmailController.text,
                                userPasswordController.text)
                            .whenComplete(() => Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                context,
                                PageTransition(
                                    child: Homepage(),
                                    type: PageTransitionType.bottomToTop)));
                      } else {
                        warningText(context, 'Fill All the Data');
                      }
                    },
                  )
                ],
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: constantColors.blueGreyColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(12.0),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(12.0),
                  )),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```

Inspect Widget:
[image]

Error:

> A RenderFlex overflowed by 190 pixels on the bottom.

The relevant error-causing widget was
Column
lib\…\landingPage\landingHelpers.dart:188
You can inspect this widget using the 'Inspect Widget' button in the VS Code notification.
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.

The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#6aa4c OVERFLOWING

I Already Did this

```
        isScrollControlled: true,
```

&

```
padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
            ),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `SingleChildScrollView`. wrap your padding with `SingleChildScrollView`

Comment: Working but me bottomsheet going to top of the screen i want to after the keyboard

Comment: give height to your bottom sheet  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2

Answer (score 5):

Wrap the container in `SingleChildScrollView`:

```
child: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.30,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(child: Column(
```